# Should I randomly pick an avatar for new users?

Tags: user-preferences

I would like my users to upload their image to their profile. The image is used in discussions and profile pages. My question is, what should I display until they upload an image? Should I have a generic shadow person or a distinguishable random avatar that people used (perhaps subconsciously when reading a discussion), much like they do here on stackexchange.

what are the pro/con for each method?

also, should i create a meaningless avatar like stackexchange, or an actual image of something? what are your thoughts?

Comment: or just use gravatar where they have likely selected an avatar already?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that differs between you randomly choosing an avatar or using a standard for users who hasn't selected one, is that it's recognizable if the user hasn't made a choice.

A form of [gamification](http://badgeville.com/wiki/Gamification) here is to make the avatar feel like "I haven't fulfilled the task of choosing an avatar" so that people will do that - *if* that's what you want them to do. It could be one of many details users has to fill in to get a 100% badge or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Giving new users a default icon that is generic gives them an incentive for customizing their profile. Giving users different icons do help with identifying different users but that is if the icon is meaningful. So I do suggest you have meaningful icons.